# Magento 2: Unable to add delete button in edit form using UI component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, admin-panel, adminform, geturl

**Getting below error while clicking on edit action from Grid.**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUrl() on
> null in
> /var/www/html/myproject/machpack/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Button/Generic.php:60
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/myproject/machpack/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Button/Delete.php(38):
> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Button\Generic->getUrl('*/*/delete',
> Array) #1
> /var/www/html/myproject/machpack/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Button/Delete.php(28):
> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Button\Delete->getDeleteUrl()
> #2 /var/www/html/myproject/magento236/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Context.php(285):
> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Button\Delete->getButtonData()
> #3 /var/www/html/myproject/machpack/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/AbstractComponent.php(116):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context->addButtons(Array,
> Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form)) #4 /var/www/html/myproject/mac in
> /var/www/html/myproject/machpack/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Button/Generic.php
> on line 60

**Generic.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Search\Controller\RegistryConstants;
/**
 * Class Generic
 */
class Generic
{
    /**
     * Url Builder
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * Registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Return the synonyms group Id.
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        $contact = $this->registry->registry('Module');
        return $contact ? $contact->getId() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show code for Generic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your Generic.php file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\ControllerName\Edit;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

/**
 * Class Generic
 */
class Generic
{
    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    protected $context;
     /**
      * @var PageRepositoryInterface
      */
    protected $pageRepository;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Return CMS block ID
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
   
    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
   
}
```

Comment: your code worked correctly. but i  still not get where i was making mistake?

Comment: Compare `getUrl` method of both